# "Fatal error: Class not found in..", Composer package not recognized

Tags: php, wordpress, class, composer-php

I ran this call in `Putty`, it successfully installed the resource:

```
php composer.phar require --dev "mikehaertl/php-pdftk:*"
```

I then added a couple of thing to my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "you/bootstrap-canvas-wp",
    "type": "wordpress-theme",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mikehaertl/php-pdftk": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
        }
    }
}
```

Next I ran an `update` command on my composer file:

```
php composer.phar update
```

I have a file located inside that theme folder `/public_html/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp` that has this code:

```
use \mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

$pdf = new Pdf('mypdf.pdf');
$pdf->flatten()
    ->saveAs('mypdf2.pdf');
```

Finally, I placed this piece of code in my `functions.php` file inside the theme folder in an effort to make these classes usable:

```
require_once(ABSPATH. '../vendor/autoload.php');
```

My code editor recognizes these resources but I get an error in my browser:

> Fatal error: Class 'mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf' not found in
>   /home/myusername/public_html/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp/flattenPDF.php
>   on line 1

Any suggestions on how to make this functional?

**EDIT**: I've also tried this syntax for the `use` statement: (same error happens)

```
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error when autoload was not called correctly.
What solved for me is:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

I use this in plain php project,the php page where i use it it is the same folder as the mikehaertl folder. So i am sure that your issue is related to this

Comment: The point here is that the path to the `vendor/autoload.php` file was wrong for me. I had to play with absolute paths and different directory locations to find where it was being served from. thanks!